# Error 26 on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have prepared a program with Visual Basic 2010 and I am using a SQL Server 2008 database. (service based database) it works properly. But sometimes (when I don't use computer for a period like 2 hours) I try to start my program on VB (F5), it waits, and then gives this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   is not accesible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server name is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified.)

I have googled it, but nothing helps. I'm afraid this error will be a problem when the user uses the program. How might I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the network connection turn off after some time. Check System Operating power setting's option

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I faced and got resolved by trying this - in run type `services.msc`:

- the services window will pop up
- in that SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) start this service.

Answer (score 0):

make sure `SQL Browser service` is running.